# Evaluating multiple lines of code inside a Do loop and extracting results

Tags: simplifying-expressions, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to use `NMaximize` to maximize a function within a looped domain, and evaluate several different expressions at each of those solutions. What I'd like to do is get the following five lines of code:

```
Print[
  NMaximize[
    {Sqrt[s] + Sqrt[t] - x s - y t, 1000000 >= s >= 0, x >= 0}, 
    {{s, 999, 1000}, t, x, y}]]
Extract[%, 2]
{s, x, t, y} /. %
3 s + 4 t^2 -3 x y
3 x + s^2 - t/y
{s, x, t, y} =.
```

To run within a `Do` loop of the form

```
Do[
  {Print[
    NMaximize[
      {Sqrt[s] + Sqrt[t] - x s - y t, 1000000 >= s >= 0, x >= 0}, 
      {{s, i 1000 - 1, i 1000}, t, x, y}]]}, 
  {i, 10}]
```

I'd basically like it to return

- Solution 1
- Expression 1 @ Solution 1
- Expression 2 @ Solution 1
- Solution 2

And so on

Comment: 1. Use `Table` instead of `Do`/`Print` 2. Use a (localized—see `Module`) variable instead of `%` 3. If you never assign to `s`, `x`, ... then there is never a reason to use `=.` on them.

Comment: Notice that `Maximize[Sqrt[s] + Sqrt[t] - x s - y t, {s, t, x, y}]` returns that "The maximum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints". Are you sure your expression can be maximized appropriately?